# .net : How to correctly catch an internet connection error during web service call?

Tags: .net, error-handling

I am calling a 3rd party web service, during testing I am simulating what would happen if the web server lost internet connectivity by disabling the network adapter during a web service operation.

I have a simple try/ catch scenario.

The ex.message is : There is an error in XML document (1, 1709).

The ex.InnerException.Message : Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

During a 2nd test : Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

My question is rather than catching a general exception, how can I catch a more specific exception relating to the transport? I've already tried a System.Net.Sockets.SocketException, but this is the wrong object type for this operation.

Any ideas?

Just for clarification, I need an error type that only occurs during a network operation fail, because I'm had a case where the web service provider made changes to their WSDL also producing an error in xml... so I need to drill down and get specific with this one...

Tried

```
catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
catch (System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException soapEx)
catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException socketException)
```

None of the above work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Catch [SoapException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapexception.aspx) and read the [Detail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapexception.detail.aspx) property.

Comment: Unfortunately its not a SOAP Exception.